# I need to make my popup form mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, popup, jotform

I am using the following code for pop up on this site: [www.kidsfirstcenter.org](http://www.kidsfirstcenter.org), and need to make this form responsive. Any ideas greatly appreciated:

```
<script src="https://d2g9qbzl5h49rh.cloudfront.net/static/feedback2.js?3.2.5236" type="text/javascript">

  new JotformFeedback({
     formId     : "50358799059976",
     buttonText : "Donate Here",
     base       : "https://secure.jotformpro.com/",
     background : "#FF0000",
     fontColor  : "#FFFFFF",
     buttonSide : "top",
     buttonAlign    : "right",
     type       : false,
     width      : 700,
     height     : 500
  });

</script>
```

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information: why is it not responsive? is it failing or just not the way you like it? do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, When opened on an Iphone it expands beyond the screen so you cannot see the form in a readable fashion.  It opens find but beyond the screen width. Does that help?

Comment: I'd say that the issue is that you are setting the width to 700 pixels, but iPhone logical resolution is lower than that (see here: http://www.iosres.com/). If you can, change the width of the form or rearrange elements so you can change it, then update the width from 700px to a lower value (eg: 480 or 550 for older iPhone versions)

Comment: Hi Alvaro, Thanks for your help. That more or less works however does not make it responsive. It just makes it smaller.  Also with the Jot form pop up code (above), it actually seems to have no effect.